# Determine exact time when sound starts playing in Portaudio

Tags: c++, audio, portaudio

I am playing a wav file in Portaudio in C++ via Qt and libsndfile. This is working just fine. I need the sound to be played with a low latency, so I'm trying to optimize my code so that the actual playing time of the file equals the theoretical duration of the file.

I noticed that the sound does not immediately start playing after I call `Pa_StartStream(stream);` but there is a small delay. I would like to know the exact time when the sound starts playing, not loading, in millisecs, because I got some other things going on dependant of that time.

The obvious way would be:

```
myTimer.start();
Pa_StartStream(stream);
```

But I think Portaudio will first call my callback function, load the buffer, and then start to play, which will invalidate my measured time, right?

How can I find out the exact time when playback starts? And while we're at it, how can I find out when it ended (I do know when I write my last data into the buffer, but I don't know when it's being played..)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can know (precisely) when the audio stream starts. You can certainly find out when it's finished by using [`Pa_SetStreamFinishedCallback`](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html#aa11e7b06b2cde8621551f5d527965838).

Comment: Thank you Mats, that helps me a lot :)